# MS Access: How can I create a YTD history table from a query that aggregates monthly data?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table where I add every month new a new record of data (key performance indicators) of that month. The table is made of 30 fields/columns. For the purpose of this question I include only three fields.

```
Table: tbl_KPIMonth, Primary Key: YearMonth
YearMonth  OrderAmount   OrderLines  OrderLinesOnTime
201311     2500          350         330
201312     3000          400         390
201401     1000          100          95
201402      500          150         140
201403     2000          200         190
201404     1500          100          90
```

I have a query that aggregates the monthly data to a current year-to-date (YTD) total for every field/column.

```
SELECT Val(Left(m.YearMonth,4)) AS Year, Sum(m.OrderAmount) AS OrderAmountYTD, 
Sum(m.OrderLines) AS OrderLinesYTD, 
Sum(m.OrderLinesOnTime)/Sum(m.OrderLines) AS OnTimeDeliveryYTD
FROM tbl_KPIMonth AS m
WHERE Val(Left(m.YearMonth,4))=2014
GROUP BY Val(Left(m.YearMonth,4))
```

Every month I want to add the YTD aggregated data to a history table to display the progress of the measure. The expected result should look like this:

```
Table: tbl_HistKPIYear,  Primary Key: YearMonth
YearMonth   OrderAmountYTD   OrderLinesYTD   OnTimeDeliveryYTD
201401      1000             100             0.95
201402      1500             250             0.94
201403      3500             450             0.94
201404      5000             550             0.93
```

Using the query above as an INSERT query doesn't work, if I include the field YearMonth, because the GROUP BY m.YearMonth would prevent from aggregating the rest of the fields.  
I must set the primary key on YearMonth to avoid duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_HistKPIYear (OrderAmountYTD, OrderLinesYTD, OnTimeDeliveryYTD)

SELECT Sum(m.OrderAmount) AS OrderAmountYTD, 
Sum(m.OrderLines) AS OrderLinesYTD, 
Sum(m.OrderLinesOnTime)/Sum(m.OrderLines) AS OnTimeDeliveryYTD
FROM tbl_KPIMonth AS m
WHERE Val(Left(m.YearMonth,4))=2014
GROUP BY Val(Left(m.YearMonth,4))
```

What can I do to have the field YearMonth in the table tbl_HistKPIYear populated with the current month (e.g. 201404)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need a cumulative query, requiring subqueries in order to achieve running sums of each month within the same year.

See my example below (I add the OrderLineYTD to show you how the last column is calculated):

```
SELECT t1.YearMonth, 

(SELECT SUM(t2.OrderAmount) FROM tbl_KPIMonth t2 
WHERE t2.YearMonth <= t1.YearMonth AND Left(t1.YearMonth, 4) = Left(t2.YearMonth, 4)) As OrderAmountYTD,

(SELECT SUM(t2.OrderLines) FROM tbl_KPIMonth t2 
WHERE t2.YearMonth <= t1.YearMonth AND Left(t1.YearMonth, 4) = Left(t2.YearMonth, 4)) As OrderLinesYTD,

(SELECT SUM(t2.OrderLinesOnTime) FROM tbl_KPIMonth t2 
WHERE t2.YearMonth <= t1.YearMonth AND Left(t1.YearMonth, 4) = Left(t2.YearMonth, 4)) As OrderLineOnTimeYTD,

([OrderLineOnTimeYTD] / [OrderLinesYTD]) As OnTimeDeliveryYTD

FROM tbl_KPIMonth t1;
```

Notice for the last column I reference the query's new column aliases instead of repeating the subqueries again.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was hoping to avoid creating 30 subqueries (one for every measure). I assume this will also have an impact on performance, won't it? I will test it.